# How do I inject an attribute into a return collection - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app that returns a collection.  I would like to inject a scope variable into each element in the collection.  How would I do this?  A foreach perhaps when I return the collection?

I am trying this but not getting very far.

```
    $scope.getPlaylist = function () {
       $http.get('genrePlaylist/' + $scope.genre).success(function (result) {
           $scope.genreTracks = result;
           angular.forEach($scope.genreTracks, function() {
               genreTracks.user = $scope.spotemail;
           });
       });
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get in `http` method? What is the structure of `result`?

Comment: I get an array of objects.

    [Object,

Comment: Thanks Egan Wolf.  Solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate every track object in array with some `user`:

```
$scope.getPlaylist = function () {
       $http.get('genrePlaylist/' + $scope.genre).success(function (result) {
           $scope.genreTracks = result;
           angular.forEach($scope.genreTracks, function(track) {
               track.user = $scope.spotemail;
           });
       });
};
```

Comment: That did it,  Thanks dfsq!

Answer (score 0):

To create a new promise with modified data, **return** the modified data to the `onFulfilled` function of the promise's `.then` method.

```
$scope.getPlaylist = function (genre, spotemail) {
    var httpPromise = $http.get('genrePlaylist/' + genre)
    //use .then method to make new promise
    var newPromise = 
         httpPromise.then(function onFulfilled(response) {
             var data = response.data;
             angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
                  item.user = spotemail;
             });
             //return modified data for chaining
             return data;
         });
     //return newPromise for chaining
     return newPromise;
};
```

Notice that I changed the `$scope` variables to arguments of the function call. This makes it easy to re-factor the code into a **factory provider** service.